# How do I force to stop a jelastic deployment process?

Tags: deployment, jelastic

It's running since hours and I can't find an option to stop or rerun in the menus.

Comment: We have registered an improvement, "JE-53762 - Handle environments stuck in deploying", whose implementation will allow aborting the deployment process in the future. There is no ETA yet.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes action on environments will be stuck if nodes(containers) in that environment are being locked by some other process. Most commonly due to the backup process. So you will need to request the Hosting team/Engineer team to check and you can either stop the locking process or wait till the lock is released.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it was the backup process, but i have waited a very long time, so, in the [Jelastic CLI](https://www.virtuozzo.com/application-platform-docs/cli/?lang=fr) :

Tried to stop (but not fully deployed obviously)

```
~/jelastic/environment/control/stopenv --envName myEnvName
```

so

```
~/jelastic/environment/control/deleteenv --envName myEnvName
```

My late 2 cents,